# Sql query to return all data in cart using multiple inner join

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Am trying to select only the items in the cart, but my query is returning all items in the product table. I don't know what was wrong with my query can someone help out on how i can archive this?

**admin**

```
id   | adminpkey | Aname 
-----|-----------|---------
1    |  adKM10   | peter
```

**item**

```
id   | IDitem  | keyAdmin | Iname | type
-----|---------|----------|-------|-------
1    | a100    |  adKM10  | car   | AA
2    | a200    |  adKM10  | house | KM
3    | a300    |  adKM10  | house | KD
```

**cart**

```
cid  | cartID  | itemID   |  buyerId  |  qty
-----|---------|----------|-----------|---------
1    | cart100 |  a100    | 100       |  3
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM cart c
INNER JOIN item i
ON c.itemID = i.IDitem

INNER JOIN admin a
ON a.adminpkey = i.keyAdmin

WHERE c.buyerId = 100'
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
$setcartdata = array();
    foreach($cartarraymarge as $data){
        $setcartdata['item_'.$data->IDitem.'_'.$data->cartID]['name'] = $data->Iname;
        $setcartdata['item_'.$data->IDitem.'_'.$data->cartID]['type'] = $data->type;
    }
var_export($setcartdata);
exit();
```

**Result**

```
array (
  'item_a100_cart100' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'car',
    'type' => 'AA',
    'qty' => 3
  ),
  'item_a200_cart100' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'house',
    'type' => 'KM',
    'qty' => 3
  ),
   'item_a300_cart100' => 
  array (
    'name' => 'house',
    'type' => 'KD',
     'qty' => 3
  ),
 )
```

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle to reproduce the results? The query seems fine so not sure where the mismatch is.

Comment: @clinomaniac okay let me do that

Comment: Why are you using `itemID` which is a string instead of using the `item.id` which is an int?  Seems like you are doing a lot of unnecessary work to create other ID's when you have perfectly good id already that is/should be the primary key and auto-incremental.   for all we know your product table is full of `a100` IDitem for every row.

Comment: @clinomaniac is working, i think is from my php code http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50005/1

Comment: @Peter - that assumes your data is correct, what's to stop duplicate `itemIDs` in your table if it's not an auto-increment ID  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3983d0/1

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix The sqlfiddle you have posted has incorrect IDitem values. Take a look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/797cb1/1

Comment: That was the point how do we know your data is correct, you say it is, but I can produce the problem you have by having incorrect data and a proper sql query, which is my point.  Also you are not using the ID field but some contrived field that may or may not be unique.  Therefor the possibility is real that it could be the case, if you had simply used the ID ,then i would think twice, but I suggest you verify your data is correct, not what you think it is, but what it actually is, it wouldn't be the first time this happened to someone.

Comment: Maybe your data is fine, but there is no way for me to know, because you are using a non-standard way of building relationships on some other key then the `id` field, that is all I am saying. Without knowing if that other key is unique or not, there is no way for me to know if it's code or data that is the problem.